# Multithreading CCLientDC possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, thread-safety

the MFC application I'm currently working on is a little hobby project, supposed to look like the green code rain from the movie Matrix. My application has the window divided into thousands of little squares, each holding a letter and each of which might need a redraw to the screen after 25 milliseconds (one frame). Currently, I tried to do this with CClientDC::TextOutW. However, depending on how many of the tiles need an update, calling TextOutW for all the necessary tiles might take anywhere from 30 to 75 milliseconds, which is obviously way too long. The output looked great, but it was just progressing too slowly.

Then I tried to use some multithreading to do the redrawing, but for that, each thread needed access to the screen. I couldn't find any documentation on whether a CClientDC can be used by multiple threads or if multiple threads can have several CClientDCs at once, writing to the same device. The multithreaded apllication I wrote compiles and runs, but the output looks pretty garbled.

I might have made a mistake somewhere (I'm not that well-experienced with multithreading yet), but then again, I might be trying to push butter through stone here. Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying to do with the CClientDC is even possible?

If multithreaded output to the screen via CClientDC is not possible, does anyone have another idea how I could output about 2000 letters on different positions onto the screen in the timespan of 20 milliseconds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I couldn't find any documentation on whether a CClientDC can be used by multiple threads"* - No, not concurrently (see [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 2: Device contexts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823)). *"does anyone have another idea how I could output about 2000 letters on different positions onto the screen in the timespan of 20 milliseconds?"* - Sure, use [Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal).

Comment: Use a single bitmap, draw onto the bitmap and bitblt it to the Window once per frame. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt

Comment: MFC/WinApi is not threadsafe (in fact assume no API is unless documented otherwise). For solutions like this I would rely on hardware acceleration e.g. use DirectX3D. Create textures for the letters and  have 2000 textured rectangles (2 triangles each) in Z order and then use an orthoganal camera looking down from above. Last time I did something like that was a long long time ago, but even then it was fast enough (10's of thousands of rectangles to draw an integrated circuit layout).

Comment: @pep *"MFC/WinApi is not threadsafe"* - That is incorrect. The majority of the Win32 API surface is threadsafe in that it never corrupts internal state. It may error out, e.g. when calling `DestroyWindow` from a thread other than the thread that called `CreateWindow`, but internal state remains consistent. Indeed, `SendMessage` is a common tool to synchronize between threads. What isn't threadsafe is the high-level outcome, e.g. when rendering from multiple threads to the same device context.

Comment: Indeed, the few exceptions where an API *isn't* threadsafe are explicitly called out in the documentation (such as [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump)).

Comment: @IInspectable It has a lot of threadlocal state in my experience, but that experience is now over 20 years old so I could be wrong there.  But this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/multithreading-programming-tips?view=msvc-170#_core_accessing_objects_from_multiple_threads  seems to indicate MFC is still not inherently threadsafe. Anyway the advise remains always check the documentation for threadsafety. (Oh and GDI still isn't : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-threads-and-gdi-objects)

Comment: @con You are confusing [`CClientDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cclientdc-class) with [`CPaintDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class). The former calls `GetDC`/`ReleaseDC`, the latter calls `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`.

Comment: Oops, obviously so... Deleted the comment, can no longer edit it.

Comment: Another example of to use GDI objects in multi-threading environment could be found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111/CThread-a-Worker-Thread-wrapper-class, second example project. Check it out. Could be a model for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone! I have read through all your suggestions, and I decided that I will try to implement my app using Direct2D after going through its learning pages. Thanks to IInspectable for suggesting it.

Comment: Can you make a "simple" test, to determine whether using multiple `CClientDC`s for the same window really works? Create two DCs, each drawing half the window? Create two threads, each one creating a `CClientDC` (or calling `GetDC()`) - once, not per character to output - and drawing half the characters. This would tell you if it works and really cuts drawing time nearly in half. You have already made some test, so I assume it wouldn't be too much work to make this too. Better post some of your (existing) code for review.